# Swarmed with comments which should be answers

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

Whenever I ask a question on StackOverflow the exact same thing happens.

People with the right answers will comment on my question, rather than set it as an answer.

I just can't understand why they don't leave their feedback as answers, is it because there's no down-vote on comments? Or these guys are just answering so many questions so quickly that they don't care about their reputation or don't have the time to fill in a proper answer.

It ruins the format of the site in my opinion as the best answers could be muddled up in with the comments under the question.

Comment: I could not find an example of this in your recent questions, could you provide a couple of links?

Comment: Short answer: they most likely not sure of themselves enough to post as answer. Just comment using `@` e.g. @Sawas and ask them to post as answer. In 90% or more of the cases they will follow and post answer you can then accept. "ruins the format of the site" is really far fetched.

Comment: More than that... in case you ask them to post as answer and they don't do that within a day or so, just post your own answer and mark accepted. Case solved. :)

Comment: Very simple questions also tend to attract answers-as-comments in my experience (yes, I plead guilty here).

Comment: If I am not sure that my solution works, I usually add a comment saying `try this... `. I Answer only if I am sure that the solution works and gives a compete solution to OP's problem.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I upvoted your comment, but... Why didn't you post it as an answer? ;-)

Comment: @sancho.s actually didn't mean to make it ironic... but it is!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I thought you didn't mean to populate the list of answers to a question marked as duplicate.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, if you need examples just look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50 Virtually all of the question in assembly listed as "unanswered" have only comments, and many of them are not just trivial comments. Take your pick. ;)

Comment: @sancho.s yeah, that too. :)

Comment: @Devolus, thanks, I especially like [`Probably, you should read PCI Device 31 Fn 6`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871319/reading-temperature-from-intel-chipset#comment26095660_17871319), which contains the canonical weasel word, usually employed when one is running on 50% memory, 50% instinct, and 0% taking 6 to 8 hours to find a suitable platform to test it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, Reading your comment from above I posted this question related to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210663/ripping-off-answers-from-comments

Comment: I frequently offer hints or a short answer as a comment. This is because answers should contain a more substantial reply, and I may not have time for that. Where a question is off-topic, again I am more likely to add a comment instead of an answer, especially if I am also voting to close.