# Ripping off answers from comments

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

There are a lot of questions which have (often enough) complex and good answers in comments, which should really be posted as answers.

A good example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50. Virtually all of the questions in "assembly" listed when using "unanswered" have answers provided via comments.

Now I was reading [Swarmed with comments which should be answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210660/swarmed-with-comments-which-should-be-answers) and notice this comment:

> More than that... in case you ask them to post as answer and they don't do that within a day or so, just post your own answer and mark accepted. Case solved. :) –  Sha Wiz Dow Ard

And I'm unsure if this was just a joke or meant seriously.

On the one hand, SO should provide answers, and it would be helpful, if the answer is provided in comments, if it were summarized in a real answer.
On the other hand, I would feel a bit like a rip off (is this the proper term?) if I would do this from somebody else's comments and possibly even get the rep for it.

Comment: You're entirely free to do so. If the other user would feel bad about the rep you're getting, they should have taken the time to post it as an answer. If you have a problem with it, make the answer CW.

Comment: @Bart, CW? What is that?

Comment: @Devolus Community Wiki

Comment: You should acknowledge the comments in your answer (at least for good form, might even be considered plagiarism if you don't), but when you do it's fine to base an answer on comments.

Comment: @ben, true, unfortunately the timing required to pull this out left little room for duplicate search :) That said, the dupe goes further by piping the original comment through another answer, which is arguably better.

Comment: I'm not sure dupe was the one I was thinking of @Frédéric; I seem to remember someone stealing a comment to answer this question before... oh well; it'll have to do.

Comment: This happened to me the other day, nearly [word for word](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20404231/969613), I wasn't that bothered, just a bit surprised!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're entirely free to do so.

If the other user would feel bad about the rep you're getting, they should have taken the time to post it as an answer. If you have a problem with it, make the answer [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/164403).

Comment: Flagged. I can't believe you did that. It's a terrible thing to take my comments and turn them into an answer.

Comment: OK, I got it. ;)

Comment: @Bart, indeed I had a problem with it, so I made the answer CW.

Comment: Bart, you should have taken the time to post it as an answer!

Comment: Gosh we are a hilarious bunch. :D

Comment: @Bart, this site is not called Meta for nothing :)

Comment: Did you two Frédéric and @Bart planned this all along? ;-)

Comment: @Sha, I see you're trying to spread the blame around. Let's not forget this all began with one of your comments ;)

Comment: I'm absolutely certain someone has done this before to the same question...